# Get values in JSON object from html input text and label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a HTML by which currently getting the values of `input` elements in loop in an array.

But now I want this in `json` object with its label.

Below is my html:-

```
<div class="vendorDaterow">
    <div class="vendorName" id="dvVendorNameData">
        <label>SP Vender Name</label><span><input type="text" value="" name="nmVendorData" id="txtVendorName"/></span>
    </div>
    <div class="vendorFromDate">
        <label>From Date</label>
        <span class="datepicker">
        <input type="text" value="" name="spFromDate" id="spFromDate" class="dateClass"/>
        <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="vendorToDate">
        <label>To Date</label>
        <span class="datepicker">
            <input type="text" value="" name="spToDate" id="spToDate" class="dateClass1"/>
            <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my js for the same

```
var arrVendorValues;
    arrVendorValues = []
    $(".vendorDaterow input").each(function () {
        var text = $(this).val();
        if (text) {
            arrVendorValues.push(text);
        }
    })
```

and output which I want is something like this

> Vendor Name: ABC, ToDate: 10/10/2010, FromDate: 11/11/2017 
>   Vendor Name: XYZ, ToDate: 10/10/2010, FromDate: 11/11/2017 
>   Vendor Name: AAA, ToDate: 10/10/2010, FromDate: 11/11/2017

Comment: you'll probably want an Object (note, not a JSON object, as such a thing doesn't exist), rather than an Array - then you use JSON.stringify on the Object to make it into JSON - which is a string

Comment: @JaromandaX: yes, u r correct. so how should I do that. I want `label` also and `input` value also in a loop. how should I proceed

Answer (score 1):

Use filter() to remove empties from collection and map() to create array

```js
var data = $('.vendorDaterow input').filter(function(){
  return this.value;// filter out empty values
}).map(function(){
  var label = $(this).closest('div').find('label').text(),
        o ={};
  o[label] = this.value;
  return o;
}).get()

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vendorDaterow">
  <div class="vendorName" id="dvVendorNameData">
    <label>SP Vender Name</label><span><input type="text" value="123" name="nmVendorData" id="txtVendorName" /></span>
  </div>
  <div class="vendorFromDate">
    <label>From Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" value="" name="spFromDate" id="spFromDate" class="dateClass" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="vendorToDate">
    <label>To Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" value="456" name="spToDate" id="spToDate" class="dateClass1" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `{[label]: this.value};` some syntax issue is coming

Comment: @VVVV actually that is es6 syntax for dynamic property name...run it will see it working fine

Comment: no its giving me error as `JavaScript critical error at line 309, column 21 in https://localhost:44300/Scripts/App/FiberEngineer.js\n\nSCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number`

Comment: ok...will fix with es5 syntax. Click run code snippet can see it works in modern browser

Answer (score 0):

Kindly add a `for` attribute to the label and iterate over it

HTML

```
<div class="vendorDaterow">
  <div class="vendorName" id="dvVendorNameData">
    <label for="txtVendorName" class="text-label">SP Vender Name</label><span><input type="text" value="" name="nmVendorData" id="txtVendorName"/></span>
  </div>
  <div class="vendorFromDate">
    <label class="text-label" for="spFromDate">From Date</label>
    <span class="datepicker">
        <input type="text" value="" name="spFromDate" id="spFromDate" class="dateClass"/>
        <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
  </div>
  <div class="vendorToDate">
    <label class="text-label" for="spToDate">To Date</label>
    <span class="datepicker">
            <input type="text" value="" name="spToDate" id="spToDate" class="dateClass1"/>
            <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arrVendorValues = [];

  $(".text-label").each(function() {

    var key = $(this).text();
    var value = $("#" + $(this).attr('for')).val();
    arrVendorValues.push({
      key: key,
      value: value
    })
  })

  console.log(arrVendorValues)
});
```

And if you need it as standalone function

```
function getInputsAsJSON() {
  var arrVendorValues = [];
  $(".text-label").each(function() {

    var key = $(this).text();
    var value = $("#" + $(this).attr('for')).val();
    arrVendorValues.push({
      key: key,
      value: value
    })
  });
  return arrVendorValues;
}
```

You can trigger it in some `click` depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create array of JSON objects. And then check the class of input element.

```js
var arrVendorValues = [];
function generateData(){
  $(".vendorDaterow").each(function () {
    var allInputs = $(this).find("input");
    var objectToAdd = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++){
      if(allInputs[i].name == "nmVendorData"){
        objectToAdd["VendorName"] = allInputs[i].value; 
      }
      else if(allInputs[i].name == "spFromDate"){
        objectToAdd["ToDate"] = allInputs[i].value;
      }
      else if(allInputs[i].name == "spToDate"){
        objectToAdd["FromDate"] = allInputs[i].value;
      }
    }
    arrVendorValues.push(objectToAdd);
  });
  console.log(arrVendorValues);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vendorDaterow">
                                        <div class="vendorName" id="dvVendorNameData">
                                            <label>SP Vender Name</label><span><input type="text" value="" name="nmVendorData" id="txtVendorName" /></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="vendorFromDate">
                                            <label>From Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" value="" name="spFromDate" id="spFromDate" class="dateClass" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="vendorToDate">
                                            <label>To Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" value="" name="spToDate" id="spToDate" class="dateClass1" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    
<button onclick="generateData();">Generate Data</button>
```

Comment: getting `object` `object` . how to get values

Comment: Initially all the inputs are empty. Either set the values in code or wrap the above code inside function and call it on button click or something after filling input box values.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create one map for holding mapping for a display name and corresponding `name` html attribute. And in an iterator, push result in JSON object instead of an array. something like this,

```
<div class="vendorDaterow">
<div class="vendorName" id="dvVendorNameData">
    <label>SP Vender Name</label><span><input type="text" value="" name="nmVendorData" id="txtVendorName"/></span>
</div>
<div class="vendorFromDate">
    <label>From Date</label>
    <span class="datepicker">

    <input type="text" value="" name="spFromDate" id="spFromDate" class="dateClass"/>
    <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="vendorToDate">
    <label>To Date</label>
    <span class="datepicker">
        <input type="text" value="" name="spToDate" id="spToDate" class="dateClass1"/>
        <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

```
var map={nmVendorData:'Vendor Name', spFromDate:'FromDate', spToDate:'ToDate'}, 
result={};
$(".vendorDaterow input").each(function (a,b) {
    var text = $(this).val();
  result[map[$(b)[0].name]] = text;

})
```

Your `result` object will hold your intended result.

If you do want to collect multiple inputs from the user, just add some `click` handler for form submission and push `result` object into some array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
        var arrVendorValues = []
        var vendorDaterowObject = $(".vendorDaterow input");

        vendorDaterowObject.each(function() {
            var text = $(this).val();
            if (text) {
                arrVendorValues.push($(this).parents('.label-input').find('label').text() + ': ' + text);
            }
        });

        $('h3').text(arrVendorValues.join(', '));
    });
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8qh1uhoy/)